# Searching BizTalk MessageBox?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Need to make a tool to search XML data from BizTalk messagebox.

How do I search all XML data related to lets say  a common node called Employee ID from all data stored in the BizTalk MessageBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BizTalk Message Box (BizTalkMsgBoxDb database) is a transient store for messages as they pass through BizTalk. Once a message has finished processing, it will be removed from the Message Box.

You probably want to research Business Activity Monitoring (BAM) which will allow you to capture message data as messages flow through BizTalk; message data can be exposed through its generic web-based portal. BAM is a big product in its own right and I would suggest that you invest time in researching all of the available features to find the one that suits your particular scenario. There are many, many resources available, however you might start by taking look at [Business Activity Monitoring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561137.aspx). There is also a very good book specifically on BAM: [Pro BAM in BizTalk Server 2009](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219149)

Alternatively, take a look at using the built-in BizTalk Administration Console tools for querying the Tracking database (BizTalkDTADb) which will hold messages for later reference based on your pre-defined configuration options. See [Using BizTalk Document Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee236914(v=bts.10).aspx).

Finally, you could consider rolling your own message tracking solution, writing message contents to a SQL Database table, as messages are received in a pipeline for example.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [BizTalk Message Decompressor](http://btsdecompress.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex! I've been using this tool for a couple of years with excellent results. Since you're hitting the messagebox directly, you should be very careful and be very familiar with the queries that you choose to execute.

As noted by a previous poster's answer, BAM and the integrated HAT queries in the admin console are the official, safest, and Microsoft prescribed answers.